# Aggregate and sum values of a list of sets and return highest value

Tags: python, set

I have a list with sets which follows the below structure. I'd like to sum all the numeric elements of the set and aggregate by color.

```
# Declare a list of sets

colors = [{"red", 1, 2},
          {"red", 2, 4},
          {"blue", 1, 2},
          {"blue", 1}]

# Iterate over each set in the list
for i in colors:
    
    for e in i:

        # sum each numeric value in the set and aggregate by color
```

Expected output:

return the color with highest sum (red)

red 9

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

colors = [{"red", 1, 2}, {"red", 2, 4}, {"blue", 1, 2}, {"blue", 1}]

d = defaultdict(int)
for c in colors:
    tot = 0
    for item in c:
        if type(item) is str:
            key = item
        else:
            tot += item
    d[key] += tot

sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[0]
```

It gives:

```
('red', 9)
```